# Pyteseract image_to_data confidence result not working correctly if configuration tessedit_char_whitelist is used

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract 5.0.1.20220118 with python 3.9.7 and need to detect text from a license plate with certain white list conditions and get the confidence for each detection:

```
pt.image_to_data(roi,lang ='eng', config="--psm 6",  output_type='data.frame')
```

On this image:

[[image]]

I get the following output:

> **conf text**
> -1.000000     NaN
> -1.000000     NaN
> -1.000000     NaN
> -1.000000     NaN
> 92.998444       B
> 95.961960  708569
> 96.753922       |

However, the "|" character is not an allowed character so I added a whitelist:

```
pt.image_to_data(roi,lang ='eng', config="--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",  output_type='data.frame')
```

And I got:

> **conf     text**
> -1.0      NaN
> -1.0      NaN
> -1.0      NaN
> -1.0      NaN
> 0.0  B708569]

But now the confidence of the detections is wrong. How can I fix this?